# WIX - Spawning a Dialog dialog during installation

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.5

Is it possible to spawn a dialog after a custom action that is scheduled in InstallExecuteSequence???

I have a two custom Action, after the first one, I need to spawn a dialog.
When the user click OK on that dialog, the dialog close and continue the second one.

But how can I spawn that dialog after the custom action is done??

Comment: what type of dialog you want to spawn? can't you do it in your first custom action?

Answer (score 1):

May not be exactly what you are looking for, but in your custom Action, if you include System.Windows.Forms you can call MessageBox.Show("...") to bring up a dialog.